# AJAX Request not logging to Google Developer Console

Tags: javascript, ajax, console.log

I have a JavaScript file linked to my main HTML file. The JavaScript file contains an AJAX request which receives some JSON data from a URL and then is supposed to log it to the console. I checked the console multiple times, but I still don't see anything. I also made sure that Log XMLHttpRequests is ticked. I use Notepad++ and the latest version of Chrome.

Here is my JavaScript

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
ourRequest.open('GET','https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json');
ourRequest.onload = function(){
    console.log(ourRequest.responseText);
};
ourRequest.send();
```

I'm learning from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJesac0_Ftw&t=1441s) if you wondered.

Comment: Check again your console because in mine it's work https://jsfiddle.net/c5ok2goe/

Comment: agreed. the fiddle works. I can think of two possibilities to check: 1) there's a problem and it's going to the error callback ("onerror"), which you haven't handled. 2) Your browser doesn't support this (as-yet) non-standard event. Try onreadystatechange instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest, in particular the section titled "Event Handlers". Maybe check your network tab as well as the console for any clues as to what's happening.

Comment: @Milaci I'm trying to see the results in Google Developer Console. When I used CodePen it worked.

Comment: So, it's not a code problem but Google Developer Console problem.

Comment: @Milaci. Yes. What is going wrong?

Comment: @jimpix i cant't check on google console to try it now.

Comment: @Milaci Ok. For the purpose of learning AJAX, I'll use CodePen for now, but in the long run, knowing why Google's Console is not working is important.